# Counter is not working properly

Tags: php, counter

I am basically creating a calendar where I want to show the attendances of students. If the student is `present` or `absent` then the counter should increase to `+1` respectively. But the problem is that if in somewhere the attendance in calendar date is not recorded then the counter fails to increase the value of `present` or `absent`.

This is the code:

```
$present_sids = explode(",",$a['present_sids']);
    $absent_sids = explode(",",$a['absent_sids']);
    $leave_sids = explode(",",$a['leave_sids']);

    if ($a['att_date'] == "1")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_1 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = '1';
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_1 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = '1';
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_1 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_1 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "2")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_2 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_2 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_2 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_2 = '';
            }
        }
    }

            if ($a['att_date'] == "3")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_3 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_3 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_3 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_3 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "4")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_4 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_4 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_4 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_4 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "5")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_5 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_5 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_5 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_5 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "6")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_6 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_6 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_6 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_6 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "7")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_7 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_7 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_7 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_7 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "8")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_8 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_8 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_8 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_8 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "9")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_9 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_9 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_9 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_9 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "10")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_10 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_10 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_10 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_10 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "11")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_11 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_11 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_11 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_11 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "12")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_12 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_12 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_12 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_12 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "13")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_13 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_13 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_13 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_13 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "14")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_14 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_14 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_14 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_14 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "15")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_15 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_15 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_15 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_15 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "16")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_16 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_16 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_16 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_16 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "17")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_17 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_17 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_17 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_17 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "18")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_18 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_18 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_18 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_18 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "19")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_19 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_19 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_19 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_19 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "20")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_20 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_20 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_20 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_20 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "21")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_21 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_21 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_21 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_21 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "22")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_22 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_22 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_22 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_22 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "23")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_23 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_23 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_23 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_23 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "24")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_24 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_24 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_24 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_24 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "25")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_25 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_25 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_25 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_25 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "26")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_26 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_26 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_26 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_26 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "27")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_27 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_27 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_27 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_27 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "28")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_28 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_28 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_28 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_28 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "29")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_29 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_29 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_29 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_29 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "30")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_30 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_30 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_30 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_30 = '';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($a['att_date'] == "31")
    {
        if (in_array($sid,$present_sids))
        {
            $red_green_31 = '70ff7d';
            $present_counter = $present_counter+1;
        }
        elseif (in_array($sid,$absent_sids))
        {
            $red_green_31 = 'ff8b70';
            $absent_counter = $absent_counter+1;
            if (in_array($sid,$leave_sids))
            {
                $l_31 = '&nbsp;(L)';
            }
            else
            {
                $l_31 = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the image of calendar:
[image]

As you can see that total presents are `6` but the total presents counter is showing only `4`

Please help

Comment: Is - `$a['present_sids']` - clean of whitespaces?

Comment: @Mr.Blue, Its clean from any white spaces. Also yes that is a counter.

Comment: Can you try print_r($present_sids); which show the input. Possibly it's not having the input

Comment: Make sure `$a['att_date']` has no whitespaces as well.

Comment: Can you provide the string input of $a['present_sids']; which is easy to debug, there is no problem in your code. Might be problem with input

Comment: Make sure accessing you're if statements is `in ascending order` with `$a['att_date'] is equals to 1` as the first input date. If not the case previous counters will be wrongly overwritten by the first if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working. What I have done is to drop the table and re-install the table again. I don't know why and how but its now working.

Thanks for every one! :)